# Android Development Tools on Mac OS X

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, adt, osx-leopard

I am trying to install the ADT plugin on Eclipse, but it doesn't seem to be working. I tried using the [ADT Bundle for Mac](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) but I always get the error

`dyld: unknown required load command 0x80000022`

on the console. I tried both `Eclipse Juno` and `Eclipse Indigo` using the eclipse `ADT plugin`, it downloaded and installed the latter, but when I go in the Preferences, there is no 'Android' there... I'm using an iMac using Mac OS X v.10.5.8 (Leopard).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because something in the bundle is made specifically for a `mac 10.6` and it isn't backwards compatible.

I'm having the same issue.

and here's my java

```
Device-873EF9:~ Tahj182$ java -version
java version "1.5.0_30"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_30-b03-389-9M3425)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 1.5.0_30-161, mixed mode, sharing)
Device-873EF9:~ Tahj182$
```

Answer (score 0):

Find out which Java version you have, it may be that your plugin requires a Java version.

Terminal:

```
$java -version
```